# Entering different cities with their population and then printing the max, min population with their respective cities

Tags: python

I have to input several cities and their population and have to print the max and minimum population with the name of the city.

I've figured out how to get the max and print it together with its country however, I dont know how to get the min.

```
n =int(input("Enter the number of municipalities "))

for i in range(n):

    city = input("Enter the municipality: ")
    population = float(input("Enter the population: "))
    #processing information to calculate sum and max, min and range
    sum += population

    if max < population:
        max = population
        maxcity = city

print("The municipality with the highest population of", max, "million was " + maxcity)
```

I need the same result for the min as I do for the max. What can I add to the if loop to make this happen? I am not allowed to use the built in max(), min() functions!

Comment: You might want to initialize your values first (I.e. before your loop). E.g. ```min = sysmaxint``` and ```max = - (sys.maxint - 1)``` or similar. Basically you need to set your starting values to the extremes so that they will trigger your if statements accordingly. Alternatively you can initialize them to the first value in your list.

Comment: Oh, if you are using python 3, i think it is ```max = sys.maxsize``` and ```min = -sys.maxsize```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
max_value = 0
max_city = ''
min_value = 10**20
min_city = ''
for i in range(n):

    city = input("Enter the municipality: ")
    population = float(input("Enter the population: "))

    if max_value < population:
        max_value = population
        max_city = city

    if min_value > population:
        min_value = population
        min_city = city

print("The municipality with the highest population of", max_value, "million was " + max_city)
print("The municipality with the lowest population of", min_value, "million was " + min_city)
```

Output:

```
Enter the municipality: f
Enter the population: 10
Enter the municipality: g
Enter the population: 15
Enter the municipality: h
Enter the population: 80

The municipality with the highest population of 80.0 million was h
The municipality with the lowest population of 10.0 million was f
```

Comment: Should also initialize the `min` to something like `MAXINT` and `max` to `-1` as well.

Comment: And you should use other names than `max` and `min` because you overwrite the built-in functions with the same name ([`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min))

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

INT_max_population = sys.maxsize  
INT_MIN = -sys.maxsize-1

max_city = ''
min_city =''

max_population = INT_MIN
min_population = INT_max_population

n =int(input("Enter the number of municipalities "))

for i in range(n):
    city = input("Enter the municipality: ")
    population = float(input("Enter the population: "))

    if max_population < population:
        max_population = population
        max_city = city

    if min_population>population:
        min_population = population
        min_city = city

print("The municipality with the highest population of {} million was {} ".format(max_population, max_city))
print("The municipality with the lowest population of {}  million was {} ".format(min_population, min_city))
```

output

```
Enter the number of municipalities 3

Enter the municipality: a

Enter the population: 1

Enter the municipality: b

Enter the population: 2

Enter the municipality: c

Enter the population: 3
The municipality with the highest population of 3.0 million was c 
The municipality with the lowest population of 1.0  million was a
```